# Was Tendulkar's infamous "shoulder before wicket" the right decision?

Tags: rules, cricket

What does "Shoulder Before Wicket" mean in cricket?
Why was Sachin Tendulkar's dismissal against Australia considered "Shoulder Before Wicket" and was it the right decision?

Answer (score 2):

> What does "Shoulder Before Wicket" mean in cricket?

In terms of the Laws of Cricket, "shoulder before wicket" means nothing at all; it is not a term defined within the Laws.

> Why was Sachin Tendulkar's dismissal against Australia considered "Shoulder Before Wicket"[?]

In terms of the official results, it wasn't. [As the scorecard shows, Tendulakar was dismissed lbw](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/15744/scorecard/63865/australia-vs-india-1st-test-india-tour-of-australia-1999-00). However, as Tendulkar was dismissed as a result of being hit on his upper arm while ducking a bouncer, the media have not unsurprisingly called this [shoulder before wicket](http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/18363162/five-memorable-leg-wicket-decisions).

> was it the right decision?

There are really two questions here:

1. Can a batsman be dismissed "lbw" even if it is not their leg which the ball contacts? This one is a definite "yes"; [quoting from Law 36.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/leg-before-wicket):

> The striker is out LBW if [...] the striker intercepts the ball, either full-pitch or after pitching, **with any part of his/her person**.

(my emphasis)<sup>*</sup>.

2. Was the ball going to hit the wicket? No-one will ever really know the answer to this, but Daryll Harper, the umpire gave him out so he was out.

<sup>* Pedantically, you would need to refer to the 1980 Code of the Laws for the wording which applied when Tendulkar was dismissed. The older Codes *used* to be on the MCC site but I can't find them any more. However, the spirit of the wording hasn't changed since then even if the exact words may have done.</sup>